# Civ 5 won't let me found a new city, why?

Tags: civilization-5

Playing Brave New world, I started a new game on my new comp I'm 56 turns into the game and now I can't build cities. I've been playing Civ 5 a long time and never had this issue. Is there a mod that is causing this? I'm Polynesian race.

Comment: Do you have settlers? Are they at least 5 tiles away from the next city?

Comment: Yes to both questions. It's only happening on desert tiles

Comment: Can you try to make another game, then try to use your settler on the desert tile and see if it works. Report back.

Comment: I can't remember the exact rules but I think there are situations where you can't build on deserts. Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: 1) Are you using any mods. 2) Is it any desert-tile or a specific one (or group)? 3) What is your happiness, is it below -10?

Comment: Screenshot and mod list would help.

Comment: Did you accidentally turn on the One City Challenge game option? Start a new game with advanced setup and check the options. I would think that blocks building settlers.

Answer (score -3):

Each city can't be 4 tiles from another.

Comment: According to the comments, this is not the problem.